# NeDB not calling back when using findOne()

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, nedb

I am creating an OAuth 2.0 service for my up-and-coming Alexa skill, and when I'm getting a client from the clients database using NeDB, there's no callback.

**getClient()**

```js
module.exports.getClient = async (clientId, clientSecret) => {
    let params = {clientId}
    let result;
    console.log("get client")
    function findClient(params) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(params)
            clients.loadDatabase()
            console.log('loaded')
            clients.findOne(params, function(err, doc) { // no callback here
                console.log('before reject')
                if (err) return reject(err)
                console.log("callback")
                if (doc.clientSecret) {
                    let secret = doc.clientSecret
                    let id = doc.clientId
                    resolve({clientSecret: secret, clientId: id})
                } else {
                    resolve({clientId: doc.oauth.clientId})
                }
            })
            console.log('does it even exec?')
        })
    }
    console.log(clientSecret)
    if (clientSecret) {
        params.clientSecret = clientSecret
    }
    result = await findClient(params)
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

Here is the request I'm making:

```
client_id=1
client_secret=secret123
username=testUser
password=testPass
```

And finally here is the express route:

```js
app.post('/oauth/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    users.findOne({name: req.body.username}, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      req.body.user = doc

      next();
    })
  }, oauth.authorize({
    authenticateHandler: {
      handle: req => {
        return req.body.user
      }
    }
  }))
```

**EDIT**: Upon adding a callback when loading the database, I got this error:

```
loadDatabase Error: More than 10% of the data file is corrupt, the wrong beforeDeserialization hook may be used. Cautiously refusing to start NeDB to prevent dataloss
```

Thank you!

Comment: Souldn't your express route call `getClient`? Or what should be the relation between `getClient` and the shown express callback?

Comment: I am using an express wrapper called `express-oauth2-server`. You can check out the package [here](https://npmjs.com/package/express-oauth2-server).

Comment: does "there is no callback" mean that it neither log `before reject` nor `callback`, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. It logs “does it even exec?” but no “callback”

Comment: nedb readme says: "if loadDatabase fails, all commands registered to the executor afterwards will not be executed..." you could try to log the result of `loadDatabase` with `clients.loadDatabase((err) => console.log("loadDatabase", err))`. Just do make sure that the db is loaded correctly.

Comment: Sure. Will do that later today

Comment: There we go, we got an error, here you go: `loadDatabase Error: More than 10% of the data file is corrupt, the wrong beforeDeserialization hook may be used. Cautiously refusing to start NeDB to prevent dataloss` Maybe I should delete the file and insert my data again?

Comment: do you have a `beforeDeserialization` hook? if no, then sure, you could try to reset your data. Good luck.

Comment: No, I don't have a `beforeDeserialization` hook. I'll reset my data and report back.

Comment: Thank you. That worked.

Comment: cool, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing out my database and inserting the data again fixed it